# If a set of vectors span a space V, does it also span any subspace of V?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For instance, if we have a set of vectors that spans $\mathbb{R}^3$, will our set of vectors also span any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Of course, they will span every subspace.

Comment: What is your definition of span? Span of a set of vectors is fixed thing. It doesn't change. Of course, it will span any subspace, the span will be a super-set (namely $\mathbb R ^3$)$of any subspace. Write down the definition of span of some set of vectors to convince yourself.

Comment: One has to be a little bit careful, since basis elements of the whole space need not belong to the subspace. Consider, for example, the plane $U=\mathbb{R}^2$ and the subspace $V=\{(x,y)\in U:y=x\}$. (This is the straight line $y=x$ through the origin.) Now the standard basis vectors of $U$ are $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$, but neither belong to the subspace $V$. So while it is true that any element of $V$ can be written as a finite sum of $e_1,e_2$, they are not a basis *in* $V$.

Comment: If a set of vectors spans $V$, then a subset of that set spans a subspace of $V$.